# Will three randomly chosen vectors from R3 be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Will three randomly chosen vectors from R3 be linearly independent?
If so, then what is the probability?**

I know that none of the three vectors can be parallel, suggesting then the probability will be less than 1.

I understand how to prove weather a set of vectors is linearly independent or dependent but I am not sure how to abstract this away to to the question.

Comment: To answer this question you first have to explain how you’re choosing “randomly” from an infinite and unbounded set of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer depends strongly on how you pick "three random vectors" in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  First, notice that your question can be reformulated as follows: "of I pick a 3x3 matrix randomly, will it be invertible"? I will interpretate your question in this way: is it true that if I pick a 3×3 matrix, then there will be an arbitrary near matrix which is invertible? In other words, I'm asking if the invertible matrices form a dense subset in the space of all matrices. The answer to this question is YES; it can be easily shown using the fact that the determinant of a matrix is a polynomial continuous function of his coefficients: if $det(M)=0$ you can perturbate the coefficients of your matrix $M$ and find an arbitrary near invertible matrix.